Fragment’s View Not Visible After Returning from Background in Jetpack Compose App
Question:
I’m developing an Android app using Jetpack Compose and Fragments. I’m experiencing an issue where the view inside a Fragment is not visible when the app returns from the background under certain conditions.
Problem Description:
I have a SampleBanner composable function that inflates a layout containing a FragmentContainerView. Within this container, I add a SampleFragment. Here’s the relevant code:
@Composable
fun SampleBanner(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, controller: SampleController) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val fragment = remember { mutableStateOf<SampleFragment?>(null) }

    AndroidViewBinding(modifier = modifier, factory = FragmentContainerLockBinding::inflate) {
        fragment.value = fragmentContainerView.getFragment<SampleFragment>()

        // Additional setup code
    }
}

In SampleFragment, I override the lifecycle methods as follows:
class SampleFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sample, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        // Initialize views and load data
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        Log.d("FragmentLifecycle", "onStart called")
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        Log.d("FragmentLifecycle", "onResume called")
    }

    // Calling the following method resolved the issue
    fun addView(v: View) {
        fl_bottom.addView(v)
    }
}

Issue:
When the app goes to the background (e.g., screen turns off or the app is minimized) and then returns to the foreground, sometimes the Fragment’s view is not displayed.
What I’ve Tried:
•   According to the report, the moment the issue was reproduced, I called the following method on the fragment and it started working:

fun addView(v: View) {
    fl_bottom.addView(v)
}

Questions:
1.  Under what circumstances would a Fragment’s view not be visible when returning from the background?
2.  How can I ensure that the Fragment’s view is properly recreated and displayed when returning from the background?
3.  Is there a recommended way to manage Fragment lifecycle within a Jetpack Compose AndroidViewBinding to prevent this issue?

Additional Information:
•   The issue occurs on devices running Android 11 and above.
•   The screen rotation is locked, so I cannot reproduce the issue using configuration changes.
•   I tried simulating low memory conditions using ADB commands, but the problem persists.
•   I’m not using setRetainInstance(true) in my Fragment.
•   I couldn’t consistently reproduce the issue, so I wasn’t able to confirm the lifecycle methods that are called when the issue occurs.

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Is there a reason you aren't using AndroidFragment, the API specifically for showing a fragment in a composable? It was introduced as part of Fragment 1.8.0.

@ianhanniballake Thanks for the great information, is there a connection between not using that feature and the above issue?

There were a number of unsolvable bugs with the AndroidViewBinding method that were fixed only when using AndroidFragment. Do you see the same issue if you switch to AndroidFragment?
